# How to remove duplicate code from array.map method?

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map, css-in-js

I am having array of data which I am maping using .map method. How can I remove duplicate code i.e.

```
<a href={usp.url}>
   <div>{usp.text}</div>
</a>
```

Code can be found on code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-haze-b9016d?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Just do `usp.display === 'a' || usp.display === 'b' || ...`  instead of having each condition separately?

Comment: Instead of adding your code to codesandbox, please add your code directly in the question.

Also as an unrelated tip - your const data declaration `const usps = [` is not in the best place.

Writing this like you have inside the App function means that the reference data usps array is recreated every time the function runs. What you probably want is to declare and intialise this const variable outside of that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
!!["desktop", "mobile", "both"].includes(usp.display) && (
    <a href={usp.url}>
        <div>{usp.text}</div>
    a>
)
```

Note: I see that you are using a map without `key`, you should always use unique keys when iterating over a list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean creating a component like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-wind-ioy0vl?file=/src/App.tsx)?

You can put your link into another component, e.g.: `MyLink` and export it from the file.

**MyLink.tsx :**

```js
type MyLinkProp = {
  url: string;
  text: string;
};
const MyLink = (props: MyLinkProp) => {
  return (
    <a href={props.url}>
      <div>{props.text}</div>
    </a>
  );
};

export default MyLink;
```

Then in your `App.tsx`, replace `<a>...</a>` with `<MyLink/>` and add the required properties to it:

```
<MyLink url={usp.url} text={usp.text} />
```